# Top answers of all, and of the tag

Tags: support, answers, search

I've been looking for it, but it can't find how to get top answers(most votes) of all time and top answers of the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web UI isn't really built around looking for answers independent of questions, so you can really only order things by questions.

You can, however, use [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com) to try and create a query that gets the data you are looking for.

**edit**

- looks like there's one for [Top Answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/316/top-answers) already

Comment: awesomr. I like to Jon Skeet one :)

Answer (score 2):

You can search with the `isaccepted:` operator and the `votes:` operator with tag you want.  You just have to keep increasing the vote count until you narrow in to the top answers.

All Time Example:

```
isaccepted:1 votes:1500
isaccepted:0 votes:1500
```

All Time Tag Example:

```
[vba] isaccepted:1 votes:20
[vba] isaccepted:0 votes:20
```

Comment: so "votes:" means votes higher than? thx

Comment: Yep, see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=a) for the advanced search operators.

Answer (score 2):

Just search for `is:answer`, then click on the votes tab to sort them by votes (most votes first).

To search for top answers in a tag, search for `is:answer [tag]` and click on the votes tab.